# How to create a unique RecyclerView for another RecyclerView in a separate activity

Tags: android-recyclerview, realmrecyclerviewadapter

I have an application in which on the first activity I create an Item in the recyclerView (a section consisting of one or two words), and by clicking on it I go to another activity where the RecyclerView is also located in which I create ordinary notes by filling out the adapter. The problem is that for each Item I need a separate recyclerView, and wherever I clicked, the same recyclerView opens[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddnev.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GSh0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's the basic data problem I think.

Maybe You're not passing the right data when an item is clicked. Try putting some logs or debug points where you pass the data in the next activity to set it in the recyclerview.